# What are the exchange rates/units of circulation of latinum?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Watching a lot of DS9 lately and am curious about latinum (gold pressed) raitos.  I’ve heard bar, strip and slip.

Are there more?

How do they translate (ie: how many slips = 1 strip).?

Comment: When is strip mentioned?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Latinum comes in 4 denominations slips, strips, bars, and bricks (from smallest to largest).

From the Memory-Alpha entry on [Latinum](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Latinum):

- Slips - One hundred slips of gold-pressed latinum are equal to one strip.
- Strips - Twenty strips are equal to one bar of latinum.
- Bars - *The exchange rate from bars to bricks is unknown.*
- Bricks

**One bar** of gold-pressed latinum is equal to **twenty strips** which is equal to **2,000 slips** of latinum.

Comment: @boxed-dinners how much latinum was the bet for? ;)