# What is latinum worth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, money, ferengi

I'm wondering if we know what latinum can buy.

Items like, for example, biomemetic gel, Romulan ale, stem bolts, or starships don't help us since they're not readily available on Amazon, as far as I know.

**Is there any canon reference to any transaction which can relate latinum to any real-world commodity?**

(Related: [What are the exchange rates/units of circulation of latinum?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10832/what-are-the-exchange-rates-units-of-circulation-of-latinum))

Comment: Likely candidate:  precious metals or gems?

Comment: Much like a Stanley Nickel, it is the same ratio of unicorns to leprechauns.

Comment: I suspect that any transaction in the books would vary greatly between authors.

Comment: Nog's sale of the tooth sharpener to Worf comes to mind. Granted, not an everyday item, but roughly comparable to, say, a nose hair trimmer or a small power tool...

Comment: What are you going to do, figure out the likely price changes in that real-world commodity in the next 300 years?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah, it's not like it's useful to say how much gold latinum can buy, since it has been explicitly mentioned several times in the series that gold is essentially *worthless*.

Comment: Hmmm but [Romulan Ale *is* available on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Star-Trek-Energy-Drink-Romulan/dp/B00290DOQ6).

Comment: @ThePopMachine with transporters and replicators, precious metals and gems are only worth the power required to assemble them.  This applies to just about every product.  The only exception I can think of is food which has noticeable differences in taste and/or nutrition due to the imprecision of most replicator recipes.

Comment: @Trisped:   In "Move Along Home", Quark accepts a bag of gems from the Wadi in trade for Dabo chips.   Plus we know that there are shipments of stem bolts.  Plus what is Cassidy Yates doing?   So you can't just say that everything is worthless because of replication technology.

Comment: @ThePopMachine If you re-read my comment you will see that I did not say they were worthless, only that they are only worth the power required to assemble them.  This of course assumes that a replicator is available which can make it.

Comment: @Trisped:  I think it's kind of hard to argue it's cheaper to use interstellar shipping rather than replication unless replication is **very** expensive.   Worthless was hyperbole.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I am not sure why you think that is my argument. Replication is not very expensive, which is why most gems and pure metals are worthless. Latinum is dense and complex (complexity being the primary problem with other non-replicatable items). Gems are crystals and crystals are simple, and there for replicatable.  The gems you are referencing are probably not gems as we know them and could compare to.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the root beer crate transaction of 10 strips.

Memory Alpha also offers this [comparative chart](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Latinum#Comparative_values)

The following provides comparison on the value of latinum for specific items. Further details of each item may be seen above.

- Clothing

  1. Cadet's uniform - five strips
  2. Dress from Garak's Clothiers - seventeen to twenty strips
- Life savings

  1. Nog - five bars
  2. Quark - one hundred bricks and six hundred bars
  3. Rom - seventeen bars, three strips, and five slips
- Wages

  1. Morica Bilby - five to thirty bars a week
  2. Quark's *[Bajoran]* employees during the Cardassian Occupation - one slip per day
  3. Quark's dabo girls on DS9 - fourteen strips per pay cycle (undetermined)
- Profits

  1. Janel Tigan - more than a thousand bars a day
  2. Quark - five bars a day
- Holosuite programs

  1. A Visit with the Pleasure Goddess of Rixx - ten strips
  2. Custom holosuite program - one bar

**I think the most relevant indicator is the wage of the Dabo girls.** They are basically dealers in a casino who are also hired for their looks. Not only do dealers earn a salary but they also often earn tips when the players are winning. We don't know what a 'pay cycle' is, but if a Bjoran slave only made 1 slip per day and a Dabo girl makes 14 strips per period (maybe 1 strip per day (in a 2 week pay period), or 100 times more than a Bajoran slave per day) and the [average Blackjack dealer](http://www1.salary.com/NV/Las-Vegas/Blackjack-Dealer-salary.html) makes roughly $601 every two weeks, we can guess that a strip is worth around $43 in today's money, and a slip is $0.43. This makes a bar worth $860.

I also have this anecdotal evidence from the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23960385#23960385).

> **Wad Cheber** - $5
>   **Jack B Nimble** - buck twenty five.
>   **phantom42** - tree-fiddy

Comment: Well, most of these items are not available today, unless you want to try to compare wages or the cost of tailoring.   It would also be helpful to canonicalize all the prices into one unit (bar or strips)

Comment: Nice. Wages are probably one of the better ways to compare currency values across the centuries.

Comment: @Junuxx Would the wage of a tailor from three centuries ago really be comparable to the wage of one today?

Comment: @Xantec: Not very precisely, but they would necessarily scale with the cost of living.

Comment: @Xantec adjusted for inflation, probably.

Comment: @NickT Alright, that is probably calculable. But what is the inflation rate between a 20th century human tailor and a 23rd century post-scarcity Cardassian (living on a Bajoran space station run by Starfleet)?

Comment: @Xantec just think about it more abstractly; if tailoring is a middle-class job (depending on how specialized and the location, and with the vague notion that DS9 is somewhat middling: an important location, but out in the middle of nowhere) in both time periods, then the real wages are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

According to Memory Alpha's entry on [latinum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Latinum):

> Quark charged Rom ten slips of latinum for a crate of root beer to be given to Nog. (DS9: "The Ascent")

Of course, that doesn't tell us much given we have no idea how much that case of root beer was worth in that time and place. If we want a ballpark figure, the script lists the crate as having "several dozen" bottles of root beer. If we assume about six dozen, that's 72 bottles. A sample of gourmet root beer prices shows that Henry Weinhard's Root Beer, Draught Style Head goes for about $15 per six, which would suggest each slip is worth about $18. Again, that's making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: I would have thought a crate of root beer is more like [this](http://mahari.club/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/njohi-ya-atumia.jpg):   around 24 bottles.

Comment: That would put a slip as more like $1-$5, ignoring the unknown rarity of the rootbeer in the future.

Comment: Ah, but how much does a case of root beer cost on a military base? And how much in a post-scarcity world, when at the very least the bottle, if not also the contents, could just be replicated? After centuries of shifts in popular drinks, is root beer a common drink or a luxury item like champagne? I mean, +1 for effort but I think the question is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: That could be too. Probably best would be someone to watch the episode and count from a still. I can't at the moment.

Comment: Could also be there's a certain cachet to the non-replicated version, much like how some people swear by mined diamonds over synthetic ones, or insist they can tell the difference between GMO and "organic" vegetables.

Comment: @Luaan Why do you say alcohol is illegal in the Federation? We know for a fact that Picard gave some to Guinan, and it was common in the ToS era.